# Eclipse: Add Maven configuration to quick links

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

If I define a maven config in "run as->run configurations" and then set one up, how can I then make it appear in the right-click -> 'run as' options?

Or failing that, where can I make the run configuration appear where it's not so buried in mouse clicks?

Comment: You mean run as > configuration  In eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

The moment you convert your project into Maven through rightClick-->configure and then update maven project you can automatically see maven clean in Run as option. From there you can build your project